Get value from different excel sheets with criteria
i want to get value from another excel sheets based on some criteria. at first look at the picture.

here in the gray highlighted cell i want to get the value from other sheet and it'll be dynamic and the criteria will be where fiscal year =2019-20. for more clarification look at the second picture. 
there could be several sheets named sheet1, sheet1(2),sheet1(3)=,Sheet1(4) and many more. now i want to search all the sheets and get only the Total amount(Marked in F colums) from where Fiscal year:2019-20 for this particular case.
Extra Information: There only one sheet contain Cell Value "Fiscal Year:2019-20" in this workbook.
I am new to excel don't get the idea of vlookup and indirect function of the excel. Please Solve this issue. thanks.

Have you followed the examples Excel gives for lookup() ? working through those should give you a good idea. But for this I would look at index() with match() and consider multiple instances. I won't do an example answer because many examples of index() with match() exist on here which show what can be achieved.

@SolarMike I think you're misunderstanding his ask. He wants to search A1 of each of the sheets, and the one that matches the cell value of the first pic take the total sum of Col F.

Pretty much as I explained, for each row in your table, iterate through all the sheets in your workbook and where right 7 characters A1 matches the value in the cell in your image, take the sum and paste the value into the greyed cell then iterate to the next row

This works, but I've had to guess the address of your list:
Sub test()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim c As Range, search_for As String
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B10") ' this is the range with the list of FYs
        search_for = "Fiscal Year: " & c.Value
        c.Offset(, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction _
            .Sum(find_sheet(search_for).Range("F:F"))
    Next
End Sub

Function find_sheet(string_to_search_A1_for) As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Cells(1, 1).Value = string_to_search_A1_for Then
            Set find_sheet = sh
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function

When you run test(), it loops through the range B3:B10 and using the value found combined with the prefix forms a string. It then sums column F of the worksheet found with that string in A1 and places it in the cell 2 to the right.

Alternatively, you could use the following UDF to find the sheet, and then use Indirect combined with that to get the value.
Function find_sheet_name(string_to_search_A1_for) As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Cells(1, 1).Value = string_to_search_A1_for Then
            find_sheet_name = sh.Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function

This can be used like so:
=SUM(INDIRECT("'"& Find_sheet_name("Fiscal Year: " & B4) & "'!F:F"))

I can't think of a way to do this with just a formula and no VBA. But then you did tag VBA in the question..

What you should have done, is name each worksheet with the Fiscal Year it represents. Then this would instead be a very simple formula.
You could use the following to rename the tabs:
Sub Rename_sheets()
    string_to_search_A1_for = "Fiscal Year: "
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(sh.Cells(1, 1).Value, Len(string_to_search_A1_for)) = string_to_search_A1_for Then
            sh.Name = Mid(sh.Cells(1, 1).Value, Len(string_to_search_A1_for) + 1, 99)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

This would then allow you to use the formula:
=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&B4&"'!F:F"))

